# Scala com.fasterxml deserialization exception

Tags: scala, deserialization, objectmapper, jackson-databind

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
//import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;

case class SparkParameters(
                              experimentName: String,
                              branch: String
                          )
val mapper = (new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper)
    .registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT)
    .asInstanceOf[ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper]

var str = """{"experimentName" : "Develop", "branch" : "copyData2gen2"}"""
mapper.readValue[SparkParameters](str)
```

**Error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "config": com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setConfig(1 params) vs com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper#setConfig(1 params)**

Can some please let me know what I am doing wrong. 
As far as t is concerned, I tried all different variations of passing the input, its not helping. 
All the Jackson versions are 2.9.8